# Confusing problem. Please help with differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Please help me find the first derivative, dy/dx, of $(xy)^x=e$

Wolfram alpha gives me the solution, how they explained to get there is confusing

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you show us what you have tried and why you are confused? Also, it helps to format question in laTex / MathJax for readability. Regards

Answer (score 1):

[Product Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) is what you need to know and to check your answer see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff%28%20x%2aln%28x%2ay%29,x%29)

$\frac{d}{dx} x\ln \left(xy\right) = \ln(xy)+1$

Comment: If you put = 1 in wolfram apha and find the dy/dx of the problem, it's a completely different answer that uses the chain and product rule. That's where it loses me

Comment: what? you question is a bit unclear why do you try to differentiate 1? One is a constant, thus when you differentiate a constant it equals zero.  Also, are you in the Reals or Complex or some other metric space?  Are you asking for which value of $x$ or $y$ will make the derivative equal to one?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to find y'. I would need to use the product and chain rule to do so. That's what confusing me

Comment: @sam are you doing differential equations? why do you have the derivative in terms of x?

Comment: To make this slightly clearer. The problem I am working asks me to find the first derivative, dy/dx, of (xy)^x = e

Comment: @Sam Then write that as your problem, and take a look at implicit differenation.

Comment: Thanks! Completely forgot about implicit differentiation. It's been years